# setInterval recount?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var sec = 10 
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
$('#timer span').text(sec--);    
if (sec == -1) {
     clearInterval(timer);  
} }, 1000);

 html

<div id="timer"><span>10</span> seconds</div>
<a href="#" id="recount">Recount</a>
```

What I want to do when I click recount is to recount back to 10 seconds the timer?

How can I possibly done it?
It is better to use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor out your code into functions so you can call the same code on startup or when the link is clicked.  You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/x3S7j/.  This even allows you to click the link during the countdown and it will start over.

```
$("#recount").click(function() {
    initCounter(10);
});

var remainingTime; 
var runningInterval = null;

function initCounter(duration) {

    function stopCounter() {
        if (runningInterval) {
            clearInterval(runningInterval);
            runningInterval = null;
        }
    }

    stopCounter();                              // stop previously running timer
    remainingTime = duration;                   // init duration
    $('#timer span').text(remainingTime);       // set initial time remaining
    runningInterval = setInterval(function() {  // start new interval
        $('#timer span').text(remainingTime--);    
        if (remainingTime < 0) {
            stopCounter();
        } 
    }, 1000);
}


initCounter(10);
```

Comment: That's work Great!! the One that exact what I want to do I got the final answer thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a click handler and factor out your code in a separate method:

```
var sec = 10;
var timer;

function startCountdown() {
    if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
    sec = 10;

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('#timer span').text(sec--);
        if (sec == -1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

$(function() {
    startCountdown();
    $("#recount").click(startCountdown);
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeABT/)

Comment: Thanks but it seems that it doesn't work 10seonds timer is not running and when I click recount it doesn't too

Comment: It works great too same does with jfriend00 Thanks Guys I really apreaciated your answer :) i'm novice in js

Answer (score 1):

When you click recount, you should

```
sec = 10;
clearInterval(timer);
timer = setInterval(that_function, 1000);
```

Also, there's a difference between `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. `setInterval` schedules the function to be called every some milliseconds. `setTimeout` schedules the function to be called once, after some milliseconds.

Comment: you have a point but how the that_function run when page load? and then that's the time will it recount when I click recount